# How i do for recognize what kind of error my function raises, using LDAP?

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

```
   try {
        CentralDataLayer cdl = new CentralDataLayerOracleImpl();
        AuthenticationDataLayer adl = cdl.getAuthenticationDataLayer();

        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        String site = request.getParameter("category");

        adl.Login(user, pass, site);
       response.sendRedirect("Configuration");

    } catch (AuthenticationException ex){
         request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid user/pass");
      } catch (NamingException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("error", "no connection");
    }
```

When exception raises, it appears only "no connection", but i want to distinguish both cases. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

It only appears that way because you coded it that way. You've thrown away the most useful part of the exception, which is the exception itself, and its message. Don't do that. Don't just create an error message of your own devising. Use the one that comes with the exception. As you test various failure modes, you will also discover that there is more than one kind of NamingException, and that you should catch them separately.